# In react for global store which is better to use in present days Redux or Context-api?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I am new to react but confused to choose between redux and context-api for my projects. Please suggest a better option with some brief.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project needs and the solution you want to go with.

In general `Redux` better if your project needs to depends a lot on the global state,
for example if you have more than 3-4 reducers you want to share with all your components, like: `auth`, `users`, `posts`.
Again, it depends on the solution you choose.

If your project only needs single global state, you can use `React context API` and avoid implementing all `redux` boilerplates and packages.

This some useful resources [When Context Replaces Redux](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-context-replaces-redux/)

Answer (score 0):

The context API with hooks is much easier to implement and will not increase your bundle size, check this article for more [Link](https://dev.to/ibrahima92/redux-vs-react-context-which-one-should-you-choose-2hhh)

Answer (score 0):

Redux is an event store and helps you debug and build complex requirements. It separates what happened (actions) with what needs to be done when a thing happens (reducer and middleware).

In context API you usually provide a function that can be called from components (so what happens is for example user clicks a button named "refresh") and that function implements what needs to be done when it happens (fetch new data).

The redux pattern is much more flexible and easier to implement complex requirement but does need a bit of understanding from the one using it. For example: user iskandar47 answer demonstrates a lack of understanding as to why redux would be useful and the article linked only has very basic requirements so context would work there.

The article does use useReducer so some separation of what happened (action) and what needs to be done when it happens (only reducer, useReducer has no middleware) can be accomplished. The problem with useReducer is that you don't have middleware, async actions or selectors. In the "who wins" bit of the article  unneeded re renders are mentioned and are caused by the lack of selectors but that is only one disadvantage, lack of reusable and composable selectors would be another.

The answer of what would be better depends on how complex your requirements are, if they are very complex (a spa usually is quite complex) then it's best to use redux.

Some of the patterns that redux uses that are useful and how they are useful are:

- CQRS: command query separation means you can write composable, memoized queries (selectors) and composable reducers (command).
- Event store: you can have a list of previous states and the actions that caused changes to those states so you can time travel (undo) and have tools such as redux devtools.
- Having state in an event store means that multiple people can more easily work on the same project. Say someone works on ui that can "add to cart", the only thing that person needs to do is dispatch the action. What happens when the action is dispatched and possible race conditions it can cause can be written by someone else with more experience or has already been written so the person cannot break that part as they only dispatch (indication something needs to happen) and not (re)implement complex logic.